# Google Analytics Universal - Remarketing Lists with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I've deployed the tracking code to support the display features as follows:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', '???', 'appnet.edu.vn');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

But when I create remarketing lists with Google Analytics, there is some warnings:

> Warning: You have created at least one remarketing list, but have not
>   made thenecessary changes to your tracking code. Without these
>   changes, your remarketing lists will remain empty and your ad
>   campaigns may not run.

As I know, Remarketing features have been supported from early April, 2014

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you added the remarketing tags on your page? Following the instructions here: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2476688

Comment: That's link is for adWords remarketing not GA remarketing

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add tags related to your business so that you can create lists based on these. See https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3455600

For example for retail you will need to send required tags such as ecomm_prodid, ecomm_pagetype, ecomm_totalvalue